# Call another page js function from server side of another page? C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am trying to achieve a notification on another page that is admin.aspx

from **register.aspx** and here is what i am doing on web method call

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Setnotification(List<string> someValues)
{ 

     Default foo = new Default();
     foo.GetNotification();
}
```

Here I comes in non static method where I want to call the js function of admin.aspx page not of same page.

```
public string GetNotification()
{
    //call here the js of admin.aspx 
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript", "AnotherFunction();", true);
    return "";
}
```

**admin.aspx** here js

```
function showmodel() {

   window.stop();
   $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
```

Now my question is how to call it?

Comment: Why not put the function in a js file and import it in both pages?

Comment: even `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(` not working